# How To Properly Import Methods

Tags: java, methods, import

I am currently working on understanding how to import other classes from a certain package in Java to another package and that certain class.

I was wondering how would I import a method from a certain class in Java to another one since I obviously can't "extend" that class to gain that method since its in some other package.

Example:

```
package Responses;

public class Hello {

    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.print("HELLO!");
    }
}
```

The question:

How do you import `sayHello` from the Hello class that's in package Responses.

```
package Start;

public class Begin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sayHello();
    }
}
```

I am not extending any classes like I stated above, so please don't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

Import the class that the function resides in:

```java
import Responses.Hello;
```

Then you can call the function: `Hello.sayHello();`

In Java, there is no construct to directly import a method, but you can import the class in which it resides.

Comment: Thanks! I got to the import part but the methods part I never actually knew you could do that by having a class and a method next to each other as such. You learn something new everyday I guess.

Comment: You can only import methods if they are static.

Comment: True, `static` methods can be imported.  Non-`static` cannot.  Good point.

Answer (score 0):

```
import static Responses.Hello.sayHello;
```

Then in your other class you can do:

```
sayHello();
```

Note: You can **only** import methods if they are **static**.

Answer (score 0):

You either import whole classes (A) or their static members (B).

A:

```
 import responses.Hello;
 public class Begin {
     String myString = Hello.sayHello();
 }
```

B:

```
 import static responses.Hello.sayHello; // To import all static members use responses.Hello.*;
public class Begin {
     String myString = sayHello();
}
```

What oracle says about the usage of static imports:

> So when should you use static import? Very sparingly! Only use it when you'd otherwise be tempted to declare local copies of constants, or to abuse inheritance (the Constant Interface Antipattern). In other words, use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes. If you overuse the static import feature, it can make your program unreadable and unmaintainable, polluting its namespace with all the static members you import. Readers of your code (including you, a few months after you wrote it) will not know which class a static member comes from. Importing all of the static members from a class can be particularly harmful to readability; if you need only one or two members, import them individually. Used appropriately, static import can make your program more readable, by removing the boilerplate of repetition of class names.

Find the whole thing [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html).

PS

Please use naming convention for your packages:

> Package names are written in all lower case to avoid conflict with the names of classes or interfaces.

That's from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make your sayHello() method public static. Like

```
public class Hello {
    public static void sayHello() {
        System.out.print("HELLO!");
    }
}
```

Then in your Begin class, you can call sayHello using Hello. Of course you should import that Hello class first if they are not under the same package.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello.sayHello();
 }
```